# Google Drive API - download quota exceeded

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm getting an error:

> The download quota for this file has been exceeded

This is a response from the drive api. I'm trying to download a file simply via following url:

```
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + media.getId() + "?alt=media\n"
```

My file is a few MBs big and I just can't download it. I'm using scribe and oauth2, I create a request, sign it and send it. The response shows me that the signature works, but I don't know why I always get the above error response from google...

Other things like retrieving a list of all my files and my user work just fine and work multiple times as well...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Android, why not try to call it using the Java API client, as discussed in the [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads) section of the documentation.

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
        try {
            // uses alt=media query parameter to request content
            return service.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAsInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to use the `webContentLink` to retrieve the download URL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll check out the Web content link tip, thanks. I don't want to use the api, I want to include many services in my app (in the end very probably more than 10) so I use an Oauth and Oauth2 approach and use the scribe library... I don't want Google api library, Facebook api library and other heavy api libraries in my app to keep it small... and to be able to reuse nearly all of my code for all data sources...

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in [multcloud](https://www.multcloud.com)
2. Add Cloud (Google Drive) &  Login and Allow Drive
3. select the file and Share get public url